# Wiremock failed to match request

Tags: java, spring-boot, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to assert previously stubbed endpoint that is being called during the OAuth2 flow:

```
        stubFor(
        post(urlPathEqualTo("/token"))
            .withHeader(AUTHORIZATION, equalTo("Basic cGluLmFwaS5jbGllbnRJZDpwaW4uYXBpLmNsaWVudFNlY3JldA=="))
            .withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, equalTo("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"))
            .withHeader(ACCEPT, equalTo(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE + "," + APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                .withHeader(CONNECTION, "Close")
                .withBody("{\n" +
                    "  \"access_token\": \"62466f2c-ff9e-4c6c-a866-b8296cf78041\",\n" +
                    "  \"scope\": \"trust read write\",\n" +
                    "  \"token_type\": \"bearer\",\n" +
                    "  \"expires_in\": 20300,\n" +
                    "}")));
```

and

```
verify(postRequestedFor(urlPathEqualTo("/token")));
```

There is a piece of log, stubbed/actual requests look equals, but Wiremock says `Header does not match`:
[image]

Could someone, please, suggest what can be wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like an issue with a space after comma, try:

```java
.withHeader(ACCEPT, equalTo(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE + ", " + APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE))
```

By the way, comparing headers with `equalTo` might be flaky. You might consider using `containing`:

```
post(urlPathEqualTo("/token"))
    .withHeader(ACCEPT, containing(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    .withHeader(ACCEPT, containing(APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, I tried proposed one at the beginning, and noticed that in such case stub exists last header only, e.g. just APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE in your example, can't figure why :(

Comment: Also, tried without space after comma with the same result